# LibGDX "GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't load image 'a.jpg'

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, textures, filehandler

Error message: "GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't load image 'a.jpg', file does not exist"

The call is:

```
Texture texture;
texture =new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("a.jpg"));
```

The application runs normally when ran as desktop application. The file exists in the core/assets folder and the war/assets folder. I am using IntelliJ IDE. Any help would be much appreciated!

**update:**
When I compile and run as a normal desktop application (gradlew desktop:run) it runs as expected. But when I run as HTML5 (gradlew.bat html:superDev) it can't find the image and Gwt throws the exception. This seems to be a Gwt run-time error.

actual output:
[image]

Comment: Where doesn't it run normally? Can you show the complete error trace?

Answer (score -1):

I've just had the same problem.

This solution worked for me.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54328/deploying-gwt-application-libgdx-and-textureatlas-problem